# Prevent HttpClient from reading cookies on PUT, POST & PATCH

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies, angular-httpclient

**How can I prevent my Angular app from trying to read *document.cookie* on PUT / POST and PATCH requests from the HttpClient?**

- My app runs in an `iframe` within another web app where accessing cookies is not allowed!
  I can't control this environment / app.
- GET requests work without any problems.
- I'm using Angular 6.0.2

#### Error

`put`, `post` & `patch` request from the `HttpClient` produce the following error.

> backend.service.ts:127 DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' 
>   property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the
>   'allow-same-origin' flag.
>       at HttpXsrfCookieExtractor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfCookieExtractor.getToken
>   (http://localhost:8080/44812272_a91e_4126_ad7b_6a54454…_sc-lightcontrol.jar/vendor.js:27596:37)
>       at HttpXsrfInterceptor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept
>   (http://localhost:8080/44812272_a91e_4126_ad7b_6a54454…_sc-lightcontrol.jar/vendor.js:27633:39)
>       at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5
>   /http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle
>   (http://localhost:8080/44812272_a91e_4126_ad7b_6a54454…_sc-lightcontrol.jar/vendor.js:27004:33)
>       at HttpInterceptingHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptingHandler.handle
>   (http://localhost:8080/44812272_a91e_4126_ad7b_6a54454…_sc-lightcontrol.jar/vendor.js:27677:27)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:8080/44812272_a91e_4126_ad7b_6a54454…_sc-lightcontrol.jar/vendor.js:26755:184)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext
>   (http://localhost:8080/44812272_a91e_4126_ad7b_6a54454…_sc-lightcontrol.jar/vendor.js:110070:27)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next
>   (http://localhost:8080/44812272_a91e_4126_ad7b_6a54454…_sc-lightcontrol.jar/vendor.js:110060:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (http://localhost:8080/44812272_a91e_4126_ad7b_6a54454…_sc-lightcontrol.jar/vendor.js:101403:18)
>       at Observable._subscribe (http://localhost:8080/44812272_a91e_4126_ad7b_6a54454…_sc-lightcontrol.jar/vendor.js:104821:20)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
>   (http://localhost:8080/44812272_a91e_4126_ad7b_6a54454…_sc-lightcontrol.jar/vendor.js:100628:25)

#### Code

`putTest()`, `postTest()` and `patchTest()` fail with the above Exception.
`getTest()` works.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
  withCredentials: false
};

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BackendService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService
  ) { }

  putTest(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('PUT test');
    return this.http.put(BackendUrl.updateDeviceToControl, mockDevicePropertyData, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log('Success')),
        catchError(this.handleError<any>('PUT test'))
      );
  }

  patchTest(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('PATCH test');
    return this.http.patch(BackendUrl.updateDeviceToControl, mockDevicePropertyData, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log('Success')),
        catchError(this.handleError<any>('PATCH test'))
      );
  }

  postTest(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('POST test');
    return this.http.post(BackendUrl.updateDeviceToControl, mockDevicePropertyData, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log('Success')),
        catchError(this.handleError<any>('POST test'))
      );
  }

  getTest(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('GET test');
    return this.http.get(BackendUrl.updateDeviceToControl)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log('Success')),
        catchError(this.handleError<any>('GET test'))
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put / Post & Patch requests work if I disable [XSRF protection support](https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection) for outgoing requests, which is enabled by default and tries to read the cookie `XSRF-TOKEN`.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule.disable(),
  ]
})
```

[HttpClientXsrfModule.disable()](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientXsrfModule#disable)